# Can you use row operations to reduce a matrix to either upper or lower triangular to find the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

For example, we have the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&1\\2&6&-14\\1&0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Using row operations $R_3+R_1$ and $R_2 + 2R_1$ and finally $-1R_1$, we arrive at $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&6&-12\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ which is an upper diagonal matrix and as such to find the eigenvalues of this we can simply do $\det(A-\lambda I)$ to achieve $$\det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&0&-1\\0&6-\lambda&-12\\0&0&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$ which because it's upper diagonal, we can simply multiply the diagonal entries to get $$(1-\lambda)(6-\lambda)(-\lambda)\\\lambda = 1,6,0$$
I believe I'm mistaken somewhere as the eigenvalues should be 2, 6, 0, but I don't know where I'm going wrong or where I'm mistaken. Can someone let me know where my understanding is mistaken.

Comment: You are correct that doing row operations to get a diagonal form does _not_ identify eigenvalues... There is no comparably simple algebraic algorithm to determine eigenvalues, unfortunately.

Comment: The basic error here for many people is that they believe if you row-reduce $A$ and get $B$ as a result, then $A$ and $B$ are effectively the same matrix.  This is definitely not true - $A$ and $B$ will (usually) be different matrices and will (usually) have different eigenvalues.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the row-reduced matrix generally have nothing to do with the original matrix.

Comment: @David Thank you. I originally googled whether or not row operations change eigenvalues and it's answer was no, but it turns out it grabbed from a T/F quiz so I guess the answer must have been False! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to correctly produce a sequence of similar matrices.  This means writing your row operations as (a product of) matrices, call that $L.$  But you must also apply inverse column operations, that is multiply on the right by $L^{-1}. \; \;$  Your first two row operations   are accomplished by multiplying on the left by

$$ L = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Try it!

We find
$$ R = L^{-1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Let us name your matrix $M$

$$ M = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 6 & -14 \\ 
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Then $LMR$   comes out

$$  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 6 & -14 \\ 
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-2 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 6 & -12 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Since the resulting matrix is triangular, the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues.

Let me repeat that this matrix really is **similar** to the original.